# Predicate in a method signature, Lambda expression

Tags: c#, lambda

The code below is just an example. The predicate of string is a 
I'm wondering if the code below may not be written more simply :

```
    public static bool IsValid(Predicate<string> condition, string test)
    {
        return condition(test);
    }
```

And the call :

```
Validator.IsValid(s => s.StartsWith("Test"), "Test with a lambda expression")
```

**EDIT**

Sorry for the lack of details. The code above is just an example but the IsValid method will take a Predicate parameter, not a Predicate so here the signature :

```
    public static bool IsValid(Predicate<T> condition, T obj)
    {
        return condition(obj);
    }
```

Comment: I'm confused. Are you asking if there's a simpler way to write `return condition(test);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I think it's cleaner to put the lambda as the last parameter, wherever possible, as it's makes the code easier to read:

```
public static bool IsValid(T obj, Predicate<T> condition)
{
        return condition(obj);
}

Validator.IsValue(foo,f=>f.Value==1);
```

Comment: It's just as useless as the previous version... why would you need a method that will just execute a predicate you provide to it? You can just as well execute the predicate yourself

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be written more simply:

```
"Test with a lambda expression".StartsWith("Test")
```

Your `IsValid` method adds absolutely no value here... If you know the predicate you're going to pass to `IsValid`, why can't you evaluate it directly instead of calling a "helper" method?

Comment: It's just for the example but the IsValid method will take a Predicate<T> parameter, not a Predicate<string>.